# How can I use a math formula as annotation text that will be displayed on mouse hover in LaTex?

Tags: math-mode, comments, annotations, pdfcomment, hide

I am using the `pdfcomment` package to annotate my PDF file, allowing comments to be hidden and revealed upon mouse hover. However, when I include a mathematical formula in the comments, it generates an error. Below is the Minimal Working Example (MWE) to reproduce the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\begin{document}
A comment appears here: \pdfcomment{Use this formula: $y = \frac{u}{v}$}
\end{document}
```

The math formula is not processed and generates the following errors/warnings:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): removing `\endgroup' on input line 5.
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): removing `math shift' on input line 5.
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): removing `\over' on input line 5.
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): removing `\begingroup' on input line 5.
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. I have no errors with your code with `pdflatex`. What build engine are you using?

Comment: @AndréC not errors, warnings, as shown.

Comment: pdfcomments are like the outline bookmarks and are pdf text strings not latex formatted output, use `\pdfcomment{y=u/v}`

Comment: @AndréC the math formula is not being processed: the output is "Use this formula: y = uv".

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Perhaps I can use y = u/v for this simple case. What should I do for a more complex mathematical expression?

Comment: it's a feature of pdf, latex can not change that, you need to express whatever you want to say as plain text